# Scala client does not automatically failover to hornetq cluster

Tags: scala, jms, hornetq

We have a Scala client that connects to the HornetQ JMS in jboss EAP , the topology is set to be collacted with two servers

1. Server A - HornetQ live Server1 and HornetQ BackupServer2
2. Server B - HornetQ live Server2 and HornetQ BackupServer1

When we try a jms client in java it automatically fails over to the back up when the live server is brought down . But the scala client cannot do failover

```
import javax.jms._ 
import java.util.{Hashtable => JHashtable}
import javax.naming._
import java.util.Calendar


object ConsumerSynchronous {

var DEFAULT_QCF_NAME = "jms/RemoteConnectionFactory"
var DEFAULT_QUEUE_NAME = "queue/steveTestQueue"
var DEFAULT_URL = "remote://ip1:port1,remote://ip2:port2"
var DEFAULT_USER = "user"
var DEFAULT_PASSWORD =  "password123!"



def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

// parse through command line arguments
for (i <- 0 until args.length) {
    var s = args(i).split("=")
    if(s(0) == "URL") {
      DEFAULT_URL = s(1)
      println("Overriding URL with " + DEFAULT_URL)
    }
    else if(s(0) == "QUEUE") {
      DEFAULT_QUEUE_NAME = s(1)
      println("Overring QUEUE with " + DEFAULT_QUEUE_NAME)
    }
    else {
      println("unknown argument " + s(0));
    }
}

val properties = new JHashtable[String, String]
properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory")
properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, DEFAULT_URL)
properties.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, DEFAULT_USER)
properties.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, DEFAULT_PASSWORD)

val ctx = new InitialContext(properties)
println("Got InitialContext " + ctx.toString())

val connectionFactory  = (ctx.lookup("jms/RemoteConnectionFactory")).asInstanceOf[QueueConnectionFactory]
println("Got ConnectionFactory")
val connection = connectionFactory.createQueueConnection
println("Got connection")
connection.start
println("Connection started")

val session: Session = connection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE)
println("Got session")
val queue  = (ctx.lookup(DEFAULT_QUEUE_NAME)).asInstanceOf[Queue]
println("Got queue")
val consumer = session.createConsumer(queue)
println("Got consumer")

val listener = new MessageListener {
  def onMessage(message: Message) {
    message match {
      case text: TextMessage => {
          println("Received message: " + text.getText)          
      }
      case _ => {
        throw new Exception("Unhandled Message Type: " + message.getClass.getSimpleName)
      }
    }
  }
}

consumer.setMessageListener(listener)
println("Message Listener set")
 }
}
```